# Updating and commiting individual files with TortoiseGit like TortoiseSVN

Tags: git, tortoisegit

A client of ours has several version-control projects set up on beanstalkapp.com .

Most of them with subversion. I installed and set up TortoiseSVN on Windows; this allowed me to have a copy of all files on my computer. If I wanted to change a file, I could right click it and choose 'Update' (to ensure it is updated to the latest version before editing), make my changes, and then right click it and choose 'Commit'. I could also select a handful of files that I had changed and commit these all at one.

The newest project uses git. I installed and set up TortoiseGit, cloning the repository on my computer, but have been finding the interface a lot more confusing.

1) I can't seem to find a way of updating just a single file, without downloading every  single changed file along the way. I believe this is done globally by right clicking the folder (rather than a file), and choosing TortoiseGit -> Pull. If I try right clicking an individual folder, there is no pull; there is a 'check for modifications' but it doesn't seem to do what it sounds like.

2) I am similarly confused with committing. If I right click and choose Git commit -> master, it does allow me to check/uncheck files which I want to change. But then it appears I also have to do a 'push', which also seems to be something global. When I tried updating a file, committing, and choosing 'push', the file was updated correctly, but Beanstalk also listed in its logs that I had made another change:

'Merge branch 'master' of xxx.beanstalkapp.com:/xxx

including a file that I hadn't touched at all. And I don't see any list of files when I choose 'push'.

I've been reading through various articles on stackoverflow for similar questions, but most seem to be for people who know lots of technical information about git; using the command line, branches, etc.

Is there any simple way of just updating one file, editing it, and committing it, or is this not possible with TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Git**, unlike Subversion, does not support parts of a *working tree* (svn: *working copy*) having different base revisions; there is always one “HEAD” commit which is the base revision for the entire tree. Nor is it possible to *download* some changes and not others; it is expected that you have the entire history available (up to the last time you fetched changes) and you navigate that history *locally* (still whole commits at a time).

You can commit partial changes using the *index*, but checkout/push/pull of commits are always operations on the entire tree.

(I'm not familiar with TortoiseGit, but if it added these features, then it would necessarily be incompatible with command-line Git due to needing to extend the repository format.)

**If you need to construct a mixed-revision state**, then first of all, the changes of interest must be in separate commits (it's generally a good idea in Git to make fine-grained commits; `git rebase -i` can be used to split and join commits before publishing them). Create a temporary branch derived from one revision of interest; then use `git merge` or `git cherry-pick` to add changes from some other branch, or `git revert` to undo past changes on the history of this branch.